# Daylight saving issues on my laptop

Tags: windows-7

My laptop fell back two hours instead of one hour on October 27th 2013 (London time). Has it got to do something with the windows 7 software that I am using? I corrected the time manually  later on.

Comment: If you have a dual or multi-boot configuration, that could account for that. Unless you give more information, I couldn't call this a problem... I mean, DST changes are twice a year (in some parts of the world, at least)